# Activity State save and restore Helper

Tags: java, android, bundle, savestate

I'd like to write some kind of helper to save and restore activity state from/into Bundle

Overriding methods `onCreate(Bundle savedState)` and `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` is  still necessary, but simple form save/restore is kinda boring

Something like this:

```
class StateHelper {

    static void restore(Bundle bundle, String[] properties, Object[] connections){
        for(int i = 0; i < properties.length; i++){
            if(bundle.containsKey(properties[i])){
                restoreState(properties[i], connections[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    static void save(Bundle bundle, String[] properties, Object[] connections){
        for(int i = 0; i < properties.length; i++){
            saveState(properties[i], connections[i]);
        }
    }

    restoreState(String s, Object o){
        if(o instanceof EditText){
            // restore state with getString
        } else if(o instanceof Checkbox){
            // save state with getBoolean
        } 
        // etc. etc. handle all UI types
    }

    saveState(String s, Object o){
        // similar to restoreState(String, Object)
        // only saving instead of restoring
    }
}
```

and use like this:

```
String[] props = {LOGIN,PASSWORD,REALNAME};
Object[] cons = {textedit_login, textedit_password, textedit_realname};
StateHelper.restore(savedState, props, cons);
// or
StateHelper.save(outBundle, props, cons);
```

And before I will spend whole day on creating this, my question is, is there any similar helper class or native way how to do this simple save/restore actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you don't need to save the UI state like you appear to do in your helper if you call through to super.onSaveInstanceState. The Android framework takes care of saving the UI state as stated in the [javadocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29):

> The default implementation takes care of most of the UI per-instance state for you by calling onSaveInstanceState() on each view in the hierarchy that has an id, and by saving the id of the currently focused view (all of which is restored by the default implementation of onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)). If you override this method to save additional information not captured by each individual view, you will likely want to call through to the default implementation, otherwise be prepared to save all of the state of each view yourself.

So for saving ui state, it's built-in, to save other state of your app you'll need some custom logic. I don't think there's any generic utility class for that.

Answer (score 1):

Views like EditText or Checkbox save/restore their states automatically, you don't need to to that manually. The restoring happens in `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`, so if you override this method, don't forget to call `super.onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`.